# Sum Values in Object

Tags: javascript, google-ads-script

I am trying to sum values from a report in GoogleAdsScript.
The report has to be segmented by campaignName, because of filter criteria.
The results should show aggregated values for IDs that exist in multiple campaigns.

I have managed to transform the report into an array and group by ID.

The last step would be to sum the values for each ID, as the GroupBy function I am using is not doing this.

Here's what I got so far:

```
function main() {
  var report = generateReport();
Logger.log(groupBy(reportArray, "Id"));
}
function generateReport() {
    var report;
    var accountSelector = MccApp.accounts()
        .withIds(['123-456-7890']);

    var accountIterator = accountSelector.get();
    while (accountIterator.hasNext()) {
        var account = accountIterator.next();
        MccApp.select(account);
        report = AdsApp.report('SELECT segments.product_item_id, metrics.cost_micros, metrics.conversions_value, campaign.name, metrics.conversions, segments.product_custom_attribute4, segments.product_custom_attribute3, segments.product_custom_attribute2, segments.product_custom_attribute1 FROM shopping_performance_view WHERE campaign.name REGEXP_MATCH ".*_PPF_.*" AND campaign.name NOT REGEXP_MATCH ".*_PPF_Y.*" AND metrics.cost_micros > 50000000 AND segments.date DURING LAST_30_DAYS ORDER BY segments.product_item_id ASC');

    }
    return report;
}
  
function formatMicros(value) {
    const micros = parseFloat(value / 1000000).toFixed(2);
    return `${micros}`;
}

var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

function reportToArray (report){
  var array = [];
var rows = report.rows();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {

        //Relevante Variablen erstellen
        var row = rows.next();
        var campaignName = row["campaign.name"];
        var offerId = row["segments.product_item_id"];
        var conversionValue = row["metrics.conversions_value"];
        var cost = formatMicros(row["metrics.cost_micros"]);
        var conversions = row["metrics.conversions"];
      
        var rowObject = {Kampagne:campaignName, Id:offerId, ConversionValue:conversionValue, Cost:cost, Converisons:conversions};

array.push(rowObject);
    }
  return array;
}
```

The result from the Logger.log look like this if the IDs are only present in one campaign:

```
{12345=[{Kampagne=SampleCampaignName1, Id=12345, Cost=84.68, Converisons=2.365506, ConversionValue=101.07449979}], 
23456=[{Kampagne=SampleCampaignName1, Converisons=15.14796, Id=23456, ConversionValue=730.58781899, Cost=120.72}], 
34567=[{ConversionValue=1185.87613113, Cost=108.33, Kampagne=SampleCampaignName1, Id=34567, Converisons=7.782904}]
```

And like this, if they are present in multiple campaigns:

```
45678=[{Kampagne=samplecampaignName1, Converisons=0.0, ConversionValue=0.0, Id=45678, Cost=65.73}, {ConversionValue=2091.72, Cost=77.34, Converisons=4.0, Id=45678, Kampagne=samplecampaignName2}]
```

How do I sum the values for Cost/ConversionValue/Conversions in this second Case?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood the task.

```
var newArr = [];
class Kampagne {
  constructor(Id, ConversionValue, Converisons, Cost) {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.ConversionValue = ConversionValue;
    this.Converisons = Converisons;
    this.Cost = Cost;
}};

var array = [
  {Kampagne:'samplecampaignName1', Converisons:3.0, ConversionValue:0.0, Id:257680, Cost:65.73},
  {ConversionValue:2091.72, Cost:77.34, Converisons:4.0, Id:257680, Kampagne:'samplecampaignName2'}, 
  {ConversionValue:100, Cost:32.04, Converisons:1.0, Id:257681, Kampagne:'samplecampaignName3'}
];
array.forEach(function(element, idx){
  let res = newArr.find((e) => e.Id == element.Id);   
  if(res==undefined) {
    newArr.push(new Kampagne(element.Id, element.ConversionValue, element.Converisons, element.Cost));
  } else {
    res.ConversionValue += element.ConversionValue;
    res.Converisons += element.Converisons;
    res.Cost += element.Cost;
  }
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it does what I expected from it. I had to add 
res.ConversionValue += parseFloat(element.ConversionValue);
res.Converisons += parseFloat(element.Converisons);
            res.Cost += parseFloat(element.Cost);

in order to get proper Values, but now I have exactly what I need :)